# Bytefield colors and baseline align

Tags: bytefield

I just found out about the `bytefield` package and read the documentation to customize the default layout a bit.

1. I followed the documentation to make sure the baselines of all fields match:

   ```
   \newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
     \centering
     \small
     \raisebox{0pt}[\bitboxmaxheight][0pt]{#1}%
   }
   ```
2. I want background colors for some fields so I copied the code for `\colorbitbox` from the documentation.

   ```
   \newcommand{\colorbitbox}[3]{%
     \rlap{\bitbox{#2}{\color{#1}\rule{\width}{\height}}}%
     \bitbox{#2}{#3}
   }
   ```

However, combining them both, prints the colored background too high.

```
\newlength{\bitboxmaxheight}
\setlength{\bitboxmaxheight}{\heightof{W}}
\newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
  \centering
  \small
  \raisebox{0pt}[\bitboxmaxheight][0pt]{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[3]{%
  \rlap{\bitbox{#2}{\color{#1}\rule{\width}{\height}}}%
  \bitbox{#2}{#3}
}
\begin{bytefield}[boxformatting={\baselinealign}]{32}
  \bitheader{0,3,4,7,8,15,16,31} \\
  \bitbox{4}{Version} & \bitbox{4}{Type} & \colorbitbox{lightgray}{8}{Unused} & \bitbox{16}{Checksum} \\
  \bitbox{32}{Group Address}
\end{bytefield}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you have hit the "send" button too early, because the list seems to be uncompleted and I cannot identify a question so far. Please press the "edit" button at the end of your question and complete the question.

Comment: Correct, Stefan. I pressed <enter> when I wanted to apply a tag, but that submitted the question. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of guessing the value of the amount of raising, measure it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,bytefield}

\newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
  \centering
  \strut\small#1%
}
\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[3]{%
  \sbox0{\bitbox{#2}{#3}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-\dp0]{\wd0}{\ht0}}}%
  \bitbox{#2}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[boxformatting={\baselinealign}]{32}
  \bitheader{0,3,4,7,8,15,16,31} \\
  \bitbox{4}{Version} & \bitbox{4}{Type} & \colorbitbox{lightgray}{8}{Unused} & \bitbox{16}{Checksum} \\
  \bitbox{32}{Group Address}
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

Instead of the trick with `\heightof`, I just insert a strut in normal size, before issuing `\small`.

[image]

Comment: With the `IEEEtran` document class this does not work and bitboxes (w/o color) are higher and get rendered on top of colored boxes of the previous line. No idea why but `IEEEtran` mangles lots of settings related to baseline spacings...

Comment: @stefanct This seems to require a new question with all details.

Comment: Does it? :) Just replace `article` with `IEEEtran` in your MWE above and you should see the problem. I have worked around it by simply using `colorbitbox`es with white background. In a new question I would not know what to ask but "how to do that but in an `IEEEtran` document?", which seems like a very bad way to spread information on your almost perfect solution for future users IMHO but I can of course do so if you want. NB: This question does not specify the document class either.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around, the following code seems to do the job. However, I would love to see a better way to use the `\raisebox` instead of determining the vertical "skip" by trial-and-error.

```
\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[3]{%
  \rlap{\bitbox{#2}{\raisebox{-1.3ex}{\color{#1}\rule{\width}{\height}}}}%
  \bitbox{#2}{#3}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @egreg's answer, I was able to come up with the following:

```
\newcommand{\baselineboxformatting}[1]{
  % Measure size of contents
  \sbox0{\small#1}
  % Use the difference between the contents' height and the bitbox's height,
  % clamped to [-.3\baselineskip, 0], as our minimum depth.
  \setlength{\skip0}{\ht0 - \height}
  \ifdim\skip0>0pt
    \setlength{\skip0}{0}
  \else
    \ifdim\skip0<-.3\baselineskip
      \setlength{\skip0}{-.3\baselineskip}
    \fi
  \fi
  \centering\rule[\skip0]{0pt}{\baselineskip}\small#1
}
```

This avoids needing to mess with `\colorbitbox` to compensate; instead, the formatting itself should automatically handle anything too large to fit in with a full `.3\baselineskip` of depth, which extends to anything, not just `\rule`.

Comment: There are spurious spaces all over the place.  This is not a good answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke Please explain? I missed of `\small` in front of both my `#1`s to match the question, but otherwise I cannot visually distinguish between the output of this and the accepted answer. Do you simply mean that I need `%` at the end of some of my lines?