# Table with fixed width columns with \multicolumn in every line

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

I want my two tables to look like in the example below, except I would like to get rid of the first row(s) (`1 to 8`). Both tables should have the same width and all fields should span the given number of columns, e.g. `Version` should be 1/8th of the total table. Without the first row, the width of all fields seems to be *random*, e.g. `Options` to `Paddings` is roughly 2:6 and not 6:2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|}
\hline
\centering{1} & \centering{2} & \centering{3} & \centering{4} & \centering{5} & \centering{6} & \centering{7} & \centering{8}\tabularnewline
\hline
Version & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Traffic Class} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Flow Label}\tabularnewline 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Payload Length} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Next Header} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hop Limit} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Source Address}}\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Destination Address}}\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{IPv6: Header Format}
\label{fig:ipv6_header}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|p{0.0925\textwidth}|}
\hline
\centering{1} & \centering{2} & \centering{3} & \centering{4} & \centering{5} & \centering{6} & \centering{7} & \centering{8}\tabularnewline
\hline
Version & \centering{}IHL & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Type of Service} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total Length}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Identification} & Flags & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fragment Offset}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Time to Live} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Protocol} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Header Checksum}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Source Address}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Destination Address}\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Options} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Padding}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{IPv4: Header Format}
\label{fig:ipv4_header}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Update**:

I switched to `tabularx` and `resizebox` so it's easier to control the size of the table. Issue remains though, as soon as I remove the first row(s), the fields don't have the correct width anymore.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering{}
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{8}{X|}}
    \hline
    \centering{1} & \centering{2} & \centering{3} & \centering{4} & \centering{5} & \centering{6} & \centering{7} & \centering{8}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \centering{Version} & \centering{IHL} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Type of Service} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total Length}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Identification} & Flags & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fragment Offset}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Time to Live} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Protocol} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Header Checksum}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Source Address}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Destination Address}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Options} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Padding}\tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\caption{IPv4: Header Format}
\label{fig:ipv4_header}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering{}
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{8}{X|}}
    \hline
    \centering{1} & \centering{2} & \centering{3} & \centering{4} & \centering{5} & \centering{6} & \centering{7} & \centering{8}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \centering{Version} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Traffic Class} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Flow Label}\tabularnewline 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Payload Length} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Next Header} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hop Limit} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Source Address}}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Destination Address}}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{}\tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\caption{IPv6: Header Format}
\label{fig:ipv6_header}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You like to have this table without the first row?

Comment: Yes, both tables without the first row (1 to 8), but both tables should  still have the same width.

Comment: The second table is too wide anyway!

Comment: than just erase both rows with lengths of  field (numbers), and instead tabular use `tabularx`: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{8}{X|}}`. Of course, in preamble you should add `\usepackage{tabularx}` ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Both are, actually. But that's a problem of the simplified example I have given and no issue in my actual document (different font size, margins etc.)

Comment: @Zarko: I tried that now and in the first table (ipv6) the version field is approximately 5 columns wide. And in the second table (ipv4), options is narrower than version/padding. Looks okay if I keep the first row though so I will switch to tabularx anyway, thanks so far.

Comment: Than be so kind an give us all relevant information! Don't leave us to rove in darkens. How can we help you? Similar figures people usually draw with some drawing package as are `pstrick` or `tikz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look, for example, at your first table, you can notice that the cells in the second column are always under the scope of `\multicolumn`. Thus TeX has no way of using the column specification.

You probably want to use the `bytefield` package; the translation is rather easy.

In the first diagram I used a `\bitheader` line, comment it out if you don't want it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=0.125\textwidth]{8}
\bitheader{0-7} \\ 
\bitbox{1}{Version} & \bitbox{2}{Traffic Class} & \bitbox{5}{Flow Label} \\
\bitbox{4}{Payload Length} & \bitbox{2}{Next Header} & \bitbox{2}{Hop Limit} \\
\wordbox{3}{Source Address} \\
\wordbox{3}{Destination Address}
\end{bytefield}

\caption{IPv6: Header Format}
\label{fig:ipv6_header}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=0.125\textwidth]{8}
\bitbox{1}{Version} & \bitbox{1}{IHL} & \bitbox{2}{Type of Service} & \bitbox{4}{Total Length} \\
\bitbox{4}{Identification} & \bitbox{1}{Flags} & \bitbox{3}{Fragment Offset} \\
\bitbox{2}{Time to Live} & \bitbox{2}{Protocol} & \bitbox{4}{Header Checksum} \\
\wordbox{1}{Source Address} \\
\wordbox{1}{Destination Address} \\
\bitbox{6}{Options} & \bitbox{2}{Padding} \\
\end{bytefield}

\caption{IPv4: Header Format}
\label{fig:ipv4_header}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Only issue: the baseline isn't aligned, but that can be fixed though: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302388/bytefield-colors-and-baseline-align
I'm not sure if I should accept this answer, because it doesn't answer why the width of fields gets *randomized* when using `tabluar(x)`.

Comment: Also: why is it \wordbox{3} and not \wordbox{4} for ipv6 source/destination?

Comment: @mgansler The argument specifies the number of lines the field should span.

Comment: @mgansler When you use `\multicolumn` in *every* cell of a column, that column is set to the minumum necessary width.

Comment: apparently I could see straight anymore. 4 is the correct value, not 3. Thanks again!