# Can't create a table with fixed column width when using \multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, width

I want to generate a table with fixed column width even though every line of it has \multicolumn.

I have seen this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318075/179187) but it's not suitable for my needs since I need to be able to control each cell's border.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{1cm}}*{2}{p{2cm}}}
&
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{strong}\\
&
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{work and steal}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{work}\\
\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}*{weak} 
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{work}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x,y)} 
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x,y)}\\
\cline{3-4}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{rest}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x,y)} 
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x,y)}\\
\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why all those `\multicolumn`s?

Comment: What should happen to "work and steal"? This is wider than `2cm`.

Comment: Probably you are more satisfied with `&work and steal
&work\\ ` instead fo your current 2 multicolumns. If you insist on using the multicolumn commands, although I can't see any reason why, you can use `&\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{work and steal}
&\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{work}\\ `.

Comment: All multicolumns to control borders. Cells can be as wide as necessary but preferably minimal.

Comment: Not all of the multicolumn commands are needed to expicitly control the borders of the table. Especially not the ones in the second row.

Comment: You're right and this solves some of the problem, but I also use multicolumn since I want to control the alignment (because when I use p{2cm} I can't center the text)

Comment: you are completely removing the `p` specification and replacing it by `c` so the column width is not specified. _if_ you need multicolumn (which seems unlikely) use p again not c.   a `p`  column entry is a parbox so you can use `\centering` to center, or for a fixed width c column use `array` package and `wc{2cm}`

Comment: Cheers! that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {*{2}{t{1cm}}*{2}{t{2.3cm}}},
  hline{3-5} = {3-4}{solid},
  vline{3-5} = {3-4}{solid},
  cells = {c},
  cell{1}{3} = {c=2}{}, % multicolumn
  cell{3}{1} = {r=2}{}, % multirow
}
     &      & strong         &       \\
     &      & work and steal & work  \\
weak & work & (x,y)          & (x,y) \\
     & rest & (x,y)          & (x,y) \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: You seem to systematically address old questions using the nice new package `tabularray` :) - are you the package author?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, I am the author.

Comment: Nice - good work! I gave you some upvotes as a "thank you".

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation of my package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccw{c}{23mm}w{c}{23mm}}
                  &      & \Block[C]{1-2}{strong} & \\
                  &      & work and steal & work \\
\Block{2-1}{weak} & work & \Block[hvlines]{2-2}{} 
                           $(x,y)$  & $(x,y)$ \\
                  & rest & $(x,y)$  & $(x,y)$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]