# Misaligment in a rule inside a bitbox

Tags: rules, bytefield

I want to draw a bytefield. In its [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/bytefield/bytefield.pdf) there are two tricks, one for baseline text aligment and one for coloring a bitfield with a rule for unused fields. I wanted to put these two suggestions together. The baseline aligment works correctly, but now If I drive in a bitbox a rule with bitboxbox height and width, it has a wrong position:

[image]

How can I set correctly both basefield and line aligment?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bytefield}

%%% Colors %%%
\definecolor{niceblue}{rgb}{.047,.372,.478}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{rgb}{.749,.937,1.0}
\definecolor{reservedfield}{gray}{0.8}

%%% cigipacket environment %%%
% This environment is the bitfield one with some customization
\newlength{\wletterheight}
\setlength{\wletterheight}{\heightof{W}}
\newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
\centering
\raisebox{0pt}[\wletterheight][0pt]{#1}%
}
\newenvironment{cigipacket}
{\begin{bytefield}[boxformatting=\baselinealign,endianness=big]{32}}
{\end{bytefield}}

\begin{document}
CIGI communication is based on packets. A packet is a byte stream of defined size, that can be fixed or variable according to packet type.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{cigipacket}
\bitheader{0-31} \\
\bitbox{8}{Packet ID = 7}
\bitbox{8}{Packet Size = 16}
\bitbox{16}{Entity ID} \\
\bitbox{8}{Field 1}
\bitbox{8}{yyField 2}
\bitbox{1}{4}
\bitbox{1}{3}
\bitbox{3}{2}
\bitbox{3}{1}
\bitbox{8}{\color{reservedfield}\rule{\width}{\height}} \\
\bitbox{32}{DOF 1} \\
\bitbox{32}{DOF 2}
\end{cigipacket}
\caption{Packet example.}
\label{fig:packetexample}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following definitions into your preamble:

```
\newlength\unalignheight
\newcommand\baselineunalign[1]%
 {\unalignheight\height
  \advance\unalignheight-\wletterheight
  \divide\unalignheight by 2%
  \raisebox{-\unalignheight}{#1}%
 }
```

and use the contents of the cell that should not get baseline-aligned as argument for `\baselineunalign`:

```
\bitbox{8}{\baselineunalign{\color{reservedfield}\rule{\width}{\height}}}
```

The effect of the new command is to compute the amount that the contents is shifted upwards and to undo this shift by a negative shift of the same size.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify `\baselinealign` and define a `\colorbitbox` command as in [Bytefield colors and baseline align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302388/bytefield-colors-and-baseline-align)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bytefield}

%%% Colors %%%
\definecolor{niceblue}{rgb}{.047,.372,.478}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{rgb}{.749,.937,1.0}
\definecolor{reservedfield}{gray}{0.8}

%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302403/4427
\newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
  \centering
  \strut#1%
}
\newcommand{\colorbitbox}[3]{%
  \sbox0{\bitbox{#2}{#3}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-\dp0]{\wd0}{\ht0}}}%
  \bitbox{#2}{#3}%
}


%%% cigipacket environment %%%
% This environment is the bitfield one with some customization
\newenvironment{cigipacket}
{\begin{bytefield}[boxformatting=\baselinealign,endianness=big]{32}}
{\end{bytefield}}

\begin{document}
CIGI communication is based on packets. A packet is a byte stream of 
defined size, that can be fixed or variable according to packet type.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{cigipacket}
\bitheader{0-31} \\
\bitbox{8}{Packet ID = 7}
\bitbox{8}{Packet Size = 16}
\bitbox{16}{Entity ID} \\
\bitbox{8}{Field 1}
\bitbox{8}{yyField 2}
\bitbox{1}{4}
\bitbox{1}{3}
\bitbox{3}{2}
\bitbox{3}{1}
\colorbitbox{reservedfield}{8}{} \\
\bitbox{32}{DOF 1} \\
\bitbox{32}{DOF 2}
\end{cigipacket}
\caption{Packet example.}
\label{fig:packetexample}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Your solution is superior ...

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with \bitboxes* as well? I tried:
\newcommand{\colorbitboxes*}[3]{%
  \sbox0{\bitboxes*{#2}{#3}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-\dp0]{\wd0}{\ht0}}}%
  \bitboxes*{#2}{#3}%
} (sorry, apparently can’t format in a comment), and that fails with “You can't use `macro parameter character #' in internal vertical mode.” This is all black magic to me, so I am stuck.

Comment: @JamesElliott Please make a followup question.

Comment: I also can’t figure out how to pass arguments like [ltb] to \colorbitbox which would be an alternative to implementing \colorbitboxes*, albeit more versbose since I have a lot of bits I want in there.

Comment: OK, thanks @egreg, I will look for the followup question interface. I am brand new to this forum.

Comment: @JamesElliott Just ask a new question and add a link to this one in the body.

Comment: All right, that’s done, thanks (that was the impression I got by finding a few example followup questions as well.) Should I clean up after myself by deleting my unreadable comments here, now?